# How to log requests when using Silex JWT authentication call and return custom message for invalid token

Tags: php, jwt, silex

I'm using `Silex` framework + `JWT` token

Sample code is as follows, Example from [this link](https://github.com/cnam/security-jwt-service-provider/blob/master/tests/mock/app.php)

```
$app->get('/api/protected_resource', function() use ($app){
    // Loggger
});
```

Everything is working fine.
If I call `/api/protected_resource` without `jwt` token it gives error as

`{"message":"A Token was not found in the TokenStorage."}`

Here I want to log the every request [with or without token] and send Custom message for invalid token.

I tried using `$app->before()`, but for invalid calls this function didn't executed.

So how to add logs for evey calls and Is there any way to configure the Custom message directly ?

Comment: For the custom message part, with Silex I use flashbag message, it's easy to use. I don't know JWT sorry, but in your controller you can do a test if token is valid : if valid do what you want, if no valid, redirect with a flashmessage maybe?

Comment: @MickaelLeger, Thanks for the reply.  I have given link in question and I'm using same for JWT token implementation. All validations are handled by their serviceporvider. Only concern here is How do I add my custom message as configuartion for invalid token.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `security.authentication.failure` event. Sample code:

```
<?php
// somewhere before calling $app->run();
$app->on("security.authentication.failure", function() use $app {
  $app['logger']->log("Authentication failure!")
});
```

This is according to the [Symfony security docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-success-and-failure-events).